# How to link properly shared linux libraries in qt?

Tags: qt, opencv, dynamic, compilation

I'd like to run my program on different computer which doesn't have  any installed libs. I build my program in QT with openCV and copied all needed .so libs to folder with all my files. Next I changed paths in QT .pro to

> INCLUDEPATH += ../
>
> LIBS += -L../ -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core.

I compiled that on my computer (linux) and it worked but I want it to work on another computer without compilation. On my friend's computer, binary doesnt work. I get error:

> ./displayImage: error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_highgui.so.3.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Did you make sure to actually ship all parts of the library? Obviously it can't find the opencv_highgui SO. Maybe the opencv_highgui library is required by the other opencv libraries (the **readelf** might not report it when run on your .elf), or maybe it is looking for libopencv_xyz.so libs without major/minor versions in their filename (the "long names" are usually for symlinking in /usr/lib).
What is the output of the **readelf** tool on your output file?

Comment: Whole output of readelf files I added to folder with project files  libopencv_highgui.so.3.1  
libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.1
[libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.1
  libopencv_core.so.3.1
   ...

Comment: It might help if you specify your system specs and versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to the directory that you're running it from.

If your files are located in `/home/abc/cool/program/displayImage` (and that folder contains all the .so files that your program needs to run)

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/abc/cool/program/
$ ./displayImage
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also add a file `<whatever>.conf` in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` and put one or more rows with the pathnames of your libraries.

Then run `ldconfig`. This is needed only once.